# adding fields to a form via javascript / jquery - how to save state

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a situation where i have to modify a form (to dynamically add a table) via jquery after it's been rendered / created.

The problem is that when the form is submitted, and redisplayed because of errors or validation issues, I don't know of a good way to save and redisplay the data they've entered into the fields I've created dynamically.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What server side technology are you using?

Comment: I'm using lua for server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to use something like [jQuery Populate](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/jQuery/demos/populate-demo.html).

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically added data don't differ from the static added ones. You have to use 'validate()' method to prevent submitting and rendering the html-code with errors, in this case user will see the dynamically added data.

Comment: which validate() method are you referring to?